# How to pattern match identical cases in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

For example, what would be a neater way of writing

```
let rec sum3 a = match a with
| [] -> false
| 1::2::xs -> true
| 2::1::xs -> true
| _::xs -> sum3 xs
```

Comment: That _is_ already pretty neat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two cases aren't identical. A list is a sequence, not a set (i.e., order is significant).

Unless you have a much larger example, I don't see a lot of possible improvements. The following is slightly more concise:

```
let rec sum3 = function
| [] -> false
| 1 :: 2 :: _ | 2 :: 1 :: _ -> true
| _ :: t -> sum3 t
```

Answer (score 2):

From the name of your function I guess you want to test if two consecutive numbers sum to 3 in which case I would write the function like this:

```
let rec sum3 = function
| [] -> false
| a :: b :: _ when a + b = 3 -> true
| _ :: t -> sum3 t
```